# Can I compare two column's values in a "before insert" trigger?

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm trying to create a trigger where an insert is stopped if the difference between two values from two different tables is a certain amount.

I have a table with persons and a table with purchases.

```
create table person(
    ssid                char(10),
    name                varchar(30),
    birthyear           year,
primary key (ssid)
)engine=innodb;

create table purchase(
    personssid          char(10),
    purchaseid          integer,
    yearpurchased       year,
    itemid              integer,
    itemname            varchar(20),
primary key(personssid, purchaseid),
foreign key(personssid) references person(ssid)
)engine=innodb;
```

What I've tried so far:

```
delimiter //
create trigger age before insert on purchase
for each row begin
    if (((select distinct yearpurchased from purchase where personssid=new.personssid)
       -
       (select distinct birthyear from person where ssid=new.personssid)<18)) then
        signal sqlstate '45000' set message_text='people under 18 are not allowed to make purchases.';
    end if;
end//
delimiter ;
```

Error code: 1242 - Subquery returns more than 1 row

```
delimiter //
create trigger age before insert on purchase
for each row begin
    declare yearpurchased year;
    declare birthyear year;
    
    select yearpurchased from purchase where new.personssid in(select birthyear from person where ssid=new.personssid) into yearpurchased;
    select birthyear from person where new.personssid in(select yearpurchased from purchase where personssid=new.personssid) into birthyear;
    if (yearpurchased-birthyear<18)) then
        signal sqlstate '45000' set message_text='people under 18 are not allowed to make purchases.';
    end if;
end//
delimiter ;
```

Error code: 1172 - Result consisted of more than one row

So what I'm trying to do in my trigger is prevent an insert on the purchase table if the person who's being inserted is under 18 years old.

I'm a beginner so I really don't understand most of the errors I get and I don't understand the logic that causes the errors most of the times.

Thank you.

EDIT: Solution:

```
delimiter //
create trigger age before insert on purchase
for each row begin
    declare years year;
    select birthyear from person where ssid=new.personssid into years;
    if (new.yearpurchased-years<18) then
        signal sqlstate '45000' set message_text='people under 18 are not allowed to make purchases.';
    end if;
end//
delimiter ;
```

Comment: SQL is all about sets. With SELECT, you describe a set of rows from a table.  The way you're using SELECT in your code, each set must have exactly one element. But your SELECTs get more than one element. That's a hint about how to remediate your problem.

Comment: Is this in both examples?

Comment: Yes. See this. https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/select-into.html  Be patient.  You'll figure this out. But try to figure it out by running your SELECTs interactively. Debugging stored code is a huge pain in the xxs neck.

Comment: I tried an alternative method and I don't get any errors now, but it's not stopping the insert. I put the new code in the original post as an edit. I don't know how to comment the code in the comments. It was too long. I'm looking at your link now, trying to understand haha.

Comment: Both triggers are invalid. The table that fires the trigger, cannot be referenced (for reading or writing) within the trigger itself. The second trigger query attempt got a little worse, for you cannot reference the same table in a subquery that is used in the outer query.

Comment: My last comment being said, I'm not clear on the need to refer back to the purchase table for a new insert? ... Could you simply check the same `yearpurchased` from the new insert attempt? For example: `if (new.yearpurchased - birthyear < 18) then ...` without having to pre-select the `yearpurchased`?

Comment: @PaulT. I managed to solve it now. I made it so much more complicated than it needed to be. Thanks alot for your help!

Comment: Please don't [edit] questions to remove the code you ask about.

Comment: @O.Jones oh ok, sorry about that. I'll readd the code. I just thought they weren't helpful for people who might have the same problem in the future. The solution was in PaulT's comment. But I'll readd the code.

Comment: @PaulT. Ofcourse. Done! Check the post.

Comment: Thanks for adding what was done for others to know!

Comment: @PaulT. No problem. Thank you for taking your time and helping me out!